# Python 3: how to send random number of bytes over the COM(serial) port

Tags: python, pyserial

I wrote a Python script in which I can send fixed bytes through a COM port.

```
ser.write(bytes('0123456789',encoding='ascii'))
```

I want to parameterize the number of bytes that the script can send.

Can anyone please suggest me how I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried creating a random-length bytes value and passing it to your ser.write() function? If not, what have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean you want to restrict the number of bytes sent to a specific value?  Suppose that ser.write has another parameter numBytes.  What happens if NumBytes is 6 in your example?  What if numBytes is 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "random" I think you mean "arbitrary", i.e. how to send an arbitrary number of bytes...

You can generate a sequence of repeating digits like this:

```
>>> ''.join([str(i%10) for i in range(21)])
'012345678901234567890'
```

The number of bytes required can be passed to the script as a command line argument. Its value will be available in the `sys.argv[]` list.

```
import sys
import serial

try:
    num_bytes = int(sys.argv[1])
except (IndexError, ValueError):
    sys.stderr.write('Usage: {} num-bytes\n'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

ser = serial.Serial()    # set up your serial port
digits = ''.join(str(i%10) for i in range(num_bytes))
num_written = ser.write(bytes(digits, 'ascii'))
```

Invoke the command like this:

```
$ python3 send_bytes.py 42
```